# Batch Convert mkv to mp4 using ffmpeg -i File1.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy File1.mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch, video-conversion

I want to batch convert all .mkv files in a folder to .mp4 format using this command:

```all-bat
ffmpeg -i File1.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy File1.mp4
```

But the problem is  I have to do it manually for every single file in the folder. I have gone through various posts , but none of them have specified for `-map` option.

I am using Windows OS and this is what I've tried so far :

```all-bat
for %%A IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy "%%A.mp4"
pause
```

This is working fine but the only problem is now I am getting `.mkv` in the converted `.mp4` files.
How can I get rid of the unwanted <strike>`.mkv`</strike>?

Comment: You may need to process those files in a script. In that vein, it may be helpful to identify the OS you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] and put the code you used **in the question** and not in comments.

Comment: Sorry for posting the code in comments section.

Answer (score 1):

```all-bat
@echo off 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%i in ("D:\Path\To\Folder\Your\Files\*.mkv"
)do ffmpeg -i "%%~fI" -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy "%%~dpnI.mp4" 

Endlocal & timeout /t -1
```

---

Just try using variables expanded:

```all-bat
"%%~fI"  - expands %%I to a fully qualified path name ==> input file 
"%%~dI"  - expands %%I to a drive letter only
"%%~pI"  - expands %%I to a path only
"%%~nI"  - expands %%I to a file name only

rem :: Concatenating "%%~dI" + "%%~pI" + "%%~nI" + ".mp4" you can get... 

"%%~dpnI.mp4"  ==> output file
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For | Refer: `more %%~OPTIONS`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**